Same picture stored several times. Am I supposed to combine them?
I don't get it. I took some photos on a semi-professional¹ camera (Sony ILCE-6000), and each picture is stored on my SD exactly six times (most of them are ARWs, some are JPGs). I swear those are the same pictures. Do cameras for some reason take six pictures every time you take a shot? Am I supposed to combine them somehow?
I never had any experience with photography before. Just wanted to do a nice thing for my friend who is living abroad.
One more thing. I rented it, so I can't say now what settings it had. I only tinkered with diaphragm, exposure, and ISO.
¹ or not, that's my classification, anyway

Most likely you had auto HDR enabled.
With that setting active the camera will take three raw (ARW) images, and it will also record two jpegs each time. The three raw images will be at different exposures, the one jpeg will be the three images combined as HDR, and the other jpeg will be the normal exposure.
If it was enabled you should have seen a "processing image" message momentarily after the images were taken.
